# Parsing a JSON object in python with special character \"

Tags: python, json, special-characters

I am having trouble parsing a JSON string in python. I have the following string:

```
{"{\"rid\":\"PHMJ3BD77P81B225A0GM\",\"sid\":\"259-2748551-5638001\",\"mid\":\"A1PA6795UKMFR9\",\"sn\":\"www.amazon.de\",\"reqs\":[{\"cap-ciba\":{\"k\":\"fwcim\",\"t\":1522150437949,\"md\":\" +I42uPPjwZf0N \",\"p\":\"https://www.amazon.de/ap/signin?clientContext":"257-0866472-4844452","openid.return_to":"https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.de%2Fkindle-dbs%2Fku%2Fku-central%3Fref_%3Dnav_youraccount_ku%26_encoding%3DUTF8","openid.identity":"http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select","openid.assoc_handle":"amzn_kplp_desktop_de","openid.mode":"checkid_setup","marketPlaceId":"A1PA6795UKMFR9","openid.claimed_id":"http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select","pageId":"amzn_aui_light","openid.ns":"http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0","openid.pape.max_auth_age":"3600","siteState":"clientContext%3D259-2748551-5638001%2CsourceUrl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.amazon.de%252Fkindle-dbs%252Fku%252Fku-central%253Fref_%253Dnav_youraccount_ku%2526_encoding%253DUTF8%2Csignature%3DikQPbHmIyj2F3VCmlAXOMRBtpWIRAj3D\"}}]}"}
```

The string origins from an HTTP request I captured on Amazon. Thus, I have no control over the input.

I want to automatically parse this String in python (using `json.loads()`). However, parsing the string does not work (`Expecting : delimiter: line 1 column 5 (char 4)`).
If I use json.laods(r"""[my_input_string]""") (convert the string into a "raw string") the object is parsed successfully.

How can I tell Python to interpret the string as raw string? I already tried `.escape("string_escape")` and `.repalce(“\\”, “\\\\”)` but both did not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about `.replace(“\\\"”, “\"”)` which will replace `\"` with `"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to remove all escape sequences.

```
In [29]: x = {"{\"rid\":\"PHMJ3BD77P81B225A0GM\",\"sid\":\"259-2748551-5638001\",\"mid\":\"A1PA6795UKMFR9\",\"sn\":\"www.amazon.de\",\"reqs\":[{\"cap-ciba\":{\"k\":\"fwcim\",\"t\
    ...: ":1522150437949,\"md\":\" +I42uPPjwZf0N \",\"p\":\"https://www.amazon.de/ap/signin?clientContext":"257-0866472-4844452","openid.return_to":"https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.de%2
    ...: Fkindle-dbs%2Fku%2Fku-central%3Fref_%3Dnav_youraccount_ku%26_encoding%3DUTF8","openid.identity":"http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select","openid.
    ...: assoc_handle":"amzn_kplp_desktop_de","openid.mode":"checkid_setup","marketPlaceId":"A1PA6795UKMFR9","openid.claimed_id":"http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fide
    ...: ntifier_select","pageId":"amzn_aui_light","openid.ns":"http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0","openid.pape.max_auth_age":"3600","siteState":"clientContext%3D259-274
    ...: 8551-5638001%2CsourceUrl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.amazon.de%252Fkindle-dbs%252Fku%252Fku-central%253Fref_%253Dnav_youraccount_ku%2526_encoding%253DUTF8%2Csignature%3Dik
    ...: QPbHmIyj2F3VCmlAXOMRBtpWIRAj3D\"}}]}"}

In [30]: from ast import literal_eval

In [31]: literal_eval(str(x))
Out[31]:
{'marketPlaceId': 'A1PA6795UKMFR9',
 'openid.assoc_handle': 'amzn_kplp_desktop_de',
 'openid.claimed_id': 'http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select',
 'openid.identity': 'http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select',
 'openid.mode': 'checkid_setup',
 'openid.ns': 'http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0',
 'openid.pape.max_auth_age': '3600',
 'openid.return_to': 'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.de%2Fkindle-dbs%2Fku%2Fku-central%3Fref_%3Dnav_youraccount_ku%26_encoding%3DUTF8',
 'pageId': 'amzn_aui_light',
 'siteState': 'clientContext%3D259-2748551-5638001%2CsourceUrl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.amazon.de%252Fkindle-dbs%252Fku%252Fku-central%253Fref_%253Dnav_youraccount_ku%2526_encoding%253DUTF8%2Csignature%3DikQPbHmIyj2F3VCmlAXOMRBtpWIRAj3D"}}]}',
 '{"rid":"PHMJ3BD77P81B225A0GM","sid":"259-2748551-5638001","mid":"A1PA6795UKMFR9","sn":"www.amazon.de","reqs":[{"cap-ciba":{"k":"fwcim","t":1522150437949,"md":" +I42uPPjwZf0N ","p":"https://www.amazon.de/ap/signin?clientContext': '257-0866472-4844452'}

In [32]:
```

Comment: Warning: while `literal_eval()` happens to "work" with this particular example, it's not garanteed it will work on any arbitrary malformed json.